# Are HTML meta tags enough?

Tags: html, seo, meta-tags

I have a webpage which is a download page for a free application (http://dragonfli.es). Because of the minimalist design, there's almost no text in this page. I was wondering if HTML meta tags could sort of help with the SEO or do I have to put some text in there?

Comment: @Auxiliary Why no text? Don't you want to introduce the visitors to your product?

Comment: @Auxiliary I recommend a big fat green "Download" button. That arrow-circle thingy doesn't cut it... `:)`

Comment: I guess I don't have much to say about it :(

Comment: @Auxiliary - Search engines tend not to like broken links... so maybe fix your blog link!

Comment: @Auxiliary Well, what is it? Is it a Windows program? What OS versions are supported? How large is the installation file? When was the program last updated? What are its features? ...

Comment: Preload your three icons by JavaScript (or CSS) please; they disappear temporarily when you hover over them the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your page you have a number of elements which are empty:

```
<div class="window"> 
    <div class="image_reel"  style = "border: 1px #707070 solid; "> 
        <a href="#"><img src="reel_1.png" alt="" /></a> 
        <a href="#"><img src="reel_2.png" alt="" /></a> 
        <a href="#"><img src="reel_3.png" alt="" /></a> 
        <a href="#"><img src="reel_4.png" alt="" /></a> 
    </div> 
</div> 
<div class="paging"> 
    <a href="#" rel="1">1</a> 
    <a href="#" rel="2">2</a> 
    <a href="#" rel="3">3</a> 
    <a href="#" rel="4">4</a> 
</div>
```

More important than having a decent page description is having content inside of your `<a>` tags and having alt attributes with reasonable descriptions of the images.

Usually in a page like this, I have something like the following:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="frontImage">
    Here is some descriptive text which goes over
    the contents of this page, and which pertains
    to the image background I'll be using.
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
#frontImage
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 400px; /* the width of the bg image */
    height: 400px; /* the height of the bg image */
    background-image: url(/img/someImage.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-indent: -999em; /* move the descriptive text off the screen */
}
```

This will allow you to have text on the page and turn that text into an image which most people will see. Just make sure that the text you're using is actually applicable to the content associate with it.

Answer (score 3):

You definitively have to put text. Search engines read the meta-tags, but they are commonly used for cheating about the site's content (think about content mirrors, fake download sites, etc.)

The real value considered for SEO is the text, and its semantics (such as `<h1>`, links and so on). The URL is also important : try to optimize its readability.

Answer (score 1):

meta tags will only do so much. google practically disregards keyword metatags completely. your best bet is to have a good URL, good page title, good h1 tag, and some relevant text. try image replacement for your header instead of an image, too.

Answer (score 1):

Add a more descriptive title. Think about what people that can be interested in your app will be looking for and try to use that query string in your title. It must be fairly short, yet descriptive.

Instead of using an image logo make it a text one. "The most simple ,fastest... TODO list" makes no sense as an image. It should be a text element. If you REALLY wana stick with an image, at least add an alt attribute to it with the same text.
Do register with Google Webmaster Tools.